# How to delete this element after it runs the animation?

Tags: javascript

The delelement code is working fine but I want to delete the element after the css animation is finished for "delorean", then I need the animation to start again every time the button is clicked, how can I use my "delelement" code to achieve this? thanks.

```
function touchDelorean(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (showDelorean == true) {
        delorean();
    }
}

function delorean() {
    var image = document.createElement("img");
    image.id = "delorean";
    image.src = "Images/delorean/" + where + ".png";
    document.getElementById("deloreanContainer").appendChild(image);

//  delelement("deloreanContainer");
}

function delelement(elem) {
    var element = document.getElementById(elem);
    while (element.firstChild) { element.removeChild(element.firstChild); }
}
```

CSS

```
#delorean {
position: absolute;
top: 0%;
left: 0%;
width: 29%;
height: 9.8%;
opacity: 1.0;
-webkit-animation: delorean_anim 10s linear;
-webkit-animation-direction: normal, horizontal ;
-webkit-animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(1, 0, 1, 0);
}

@-webkit-keyframes delorean_anim {
0% { -webkit-transform: translate(-24vw, 0vw) scale(0.6, 0.6) rotate(0deg) }
20% { -webkit-transform: translate(137vw, 36vw) scale(3.5, 3.5) rotate(0deg) }
100% { -webkit-transform: translate(137vw, 36vw) scale(3.5, 3.5) rotate(0deg)}
}
```

Comment: `setTimeout()` is your friend. Made an answer example for you. Also, consider moving to jQuery for easier-to-read and more efficient JavaScript :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `setTimeout()` and do a time equal or greater to that of your CSS Transition time... so if:

```
transition: all 3s ease;
```

then...

```
function delorean() {
    var image = document.createElement("img");
    image.id = "delorean";
    image.src = "Images/delorean/" + where + ".png";
    document.getElementById("deloreanContainer").appendChild(image);

    setTimeout( function { delelement("deloreanContainer"); }, 3000 );
}

function delelement(elem) {
    var element = document.getElementById(elem);
    while (element.firstChild) { element.removeChild(element.firstChild); }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but this breaks the widget, not sure why.

Comment: I got it working, thank you!    setTimeout(function(){ delelement("deloreanContainer"); }, 10000);

Answer (score 2):

On the element that runs the animation, given that it is `image` you can add an eventlistener..

```
// Chrome, Safari and Opera
image.addEventListener('webkitAnimationEnd', function() {
  image.remove()
});

// Standard syntax
image.addEventListener('animationend', function() {
  image.remove()
});
```

If you're dealing with a css transition and not a css animation then you're looking for `transitionend`. These events can however be unreliable sometimes so if you know the length of the animation, you're better off with `setTimeout` as suggested above.

In react.js the infamous CSSTransitionGroup component had many problems due to the transition event not fireing as expected. They "solved" the problem by requiring specifying transition timeout values for the component..

Comment: This is a better solution for more modern browsers, as it avoids needing to code the duration in two separate places, with two different values (`3s` and `3000`) for the same duration.

Comment: This solution does give large benefits in that you don't have to match times in separate places, but you'll take a risk with the support of those two events. As support becomes more accross-the-board, this would definitely be the better approach.

Comment: Thanks, I thought this was going to work but the image remains after the animation, I added the css animation to the original post.

Comment: Ah, turns out the eventname is different on safari, chrome and opera